# VBA sumifs - ignore criteria if not found

Tags: excel, vba, sumifs

Is there a way to create a sumifs function that ignores any criteria that aren't satisfied, and continues to sum based off of the other criteria?

Hope that makes sense...

Comment: I don't see any sense in ignoring a criteria that is not satisfied. Then you can just remove the criteria. If it is equal if the criteria is fulfilled or not then you don't need the criteria.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit short..., but yes it is possible:
Put a countif on your Criteria and act when the result of the Countif = 0

```
=SUMIFS(C1:C6;A1:A6;IF(COUNTIF(A1:A6;H1)=0;"*";H1);B1:B6;1)
```

So when Criteria in H1 is not met this is replaced with * so it continues to the other criteria